# Create a java image from a RTP paket (h264) (pure Java?)

Tags: java, image, h.264, rtp

Does someone know, how is it possible to create an Java image from a RTP paket, without external librarys?

The RTP- payload (content) and length are available, the RTP stream is h264.

I found some code like that below, but it looks like for me, that this code works only for mjpeg stream? right, wrong?:

```
 int payload_length = rtp_packet.getpayload_length();
 byte [] payload = new byte[payload_length];
 rtp_packet.getpayload(payload);

 Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
 Image img = toolkit.createImage(rtp_packet.payload, 0,rtp_packet.getpayload_length());
```

if i execute this code, a receive the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (-1) and height (-1) cannot be <= 0
at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1016)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:324)
at extern.UDPClient.toBufferedImage(UDPClient.java:133)
at extern.UDPClient.receive(UDPClient.java:110)
at extern.UDPClient.<init>(UDPClient.java:66)
```

Extra informations:

RTP.paket.length=1012

Payload_type=96

as far as i search for answers, looks like i need an additional library. What is meaning for me, pure java doesnt work, right or wrong? 
JCodec looks good, but also there i am unable to find a method, which take the raw rtp.payload and creates me an java image :/

thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

“Possible, Yes

> without external librarys?

Yes, but you need to become a video compresssion expert and write an h.264 decoder.

Comment: Sounds like long weeks / month of work... i found jcodec but wasnt Lucky to find a method with which one i can accomplish the job described earlyer. You have some tips/ sample Code for me?

Comment: Probably years of work. My tip is use an external library.